# Deleting Workspace Post Maven Execution in LInux Machine

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our frame work is developed in a way that the whole project will be copied (from Perforce) to Linux machine (remote VM machine) and there a Maven command is executed to run test cases. Everything is driven through Jenkins.

After executing the test cases, I delete the workspace using an **Execute shell** post Maven build step. As expected it's deleting the workspace. My problem after deleting the workspace: not sure why again it's parsing POM? This causes the job to fail though test cases executed successfully.

This is how I configured to delete the workspace:

[image]

Upon running job, it's deleting the workspace as expected but parsing POM post deletion. Obviously POM will not be there as it deleted the workspace.

```
INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:11:26.091s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 02 22:50:42 PST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 133M/489M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
[testjob] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson464395510348605766.sh
+ echo testjob
testjob
+ delworkspace=/opt/hudson/workspace/testjob
+ rm -rf /opt/hudson/workspace/testjob
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/hudson/workspace/testjob/pom.xml (No such file or directory)
    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream.read(FastPipedInputStream.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Do I miss anything in configuration? I did all homework, but no luck.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins is this? I don't remember having seen a **Post Steps** section for the last three years. I just know this section as **Post-build Actions**.

Comment: i use Jenkins 1.610. Now i enabled Workspace Cleanup Plugin under section Post-build Actions. Thanks for teaching me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin):

> This plugin deletes the workspace before the build or when a build is finished and artifacts saved.

instead of removing the workspace via an own script.

Comment: Thanks @Gerold 
what command do i have to pass in "External Deletion Command"?
 i have given following command "sh -c "rm -rf /opt/hudson/workspace/*"" but no success

Comment: if require i can share configuration

Comment: @Mona You don't need an _External Deletion Command_ for deleting the entire workspace. See inline help of _Patterns for files to be deleted_: „_By default, the entire workspace will be deleted._“

Comment: Thanks @Gerold, i tried with no pattern and no external deletion command. it worked. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) easily.

- What you should do: create a new job (say, named `cleanWS`), when build is completed, it will trigger `cleanWS` & delete your job's workspace instantly.
- Go `testjob` configure -> select `Execute shell` from `Build` section -> copy and paste `echo delworkspace=/opt/hudson/workspace/$JOB_NAME >> file.properties`.
- In `Post-build Actions` section:

  ```
    Add post-build action -> Trigger parameterized build on the projects
    Projects to build -> <job name e.g. cleanWS>  
    Trigger when build is -> Complete (always trigger)
    Add Parameters -> Parameters from properties file
      Use properties from file -> file.properties
  ```
- press `save`.
- Then go your `cleanWS` configure -> select `Execute shell` from `Build` section -> copy and paste `rm -rf $delworkspace`.

N.B. With this `cleanWS` job you can delete your all job's workspace.